# Apache - Avoiding ISP Blocking for Medical Training

Tags: php, apache, blocking, medical

One of our systems is an online training platform which delivers dynamic online training to medical professionals, such as the NHS (UK) nurses and because of the medical nature of our training some "offensive" sexual and medical words are used to train the nurses and teachers in schools about chi1d safety and other such subjects.

Due to the recent censoring of the UK internet our content will soon be blocked due to it being deemed unsafe for work or for children, this will not only destroy our business but stop the nurses and teachers accessing their vital training...

We use Linux VPS (Debian) with Apache and PHP, we have several domains all pointing to the one platform serving textual and JPG, GIF, animations etc.

Apart from continually changing domain names, IP addresses or client side work-around's like VPN/proxy/tor or the client requesting that (the wrongly categorized) "prawn-oh-graphite material" be turned back On... is there a technical solution to avoid this ridiculous way of blind ignorant censoring?

We have already spoken with BT (British Telecom) about if/when our nationally recognized training will be blocked and although they agree that we should not be blocked and it's vital to train our type of clients, they confirm it will happen and their hands are tied due to politics, there is no white-list nor anything we can do, they recon.

I appeal to my fellow IT professionals to help us survive and train our teachers and nurses via any technical means possible, preferably server side. I'm at a loss :(

P.S. I'm hesitant to mention our brand names (on stackoverflow) as we deliver content via many commercial and safety group partners... *Although, I'm sure if you were to search around you could come across this information yourself if you require validation, DNS etc. or if truly necessary I will list some of our domains.*

P.P.S. I've now signed http://epetitions.direct.gov.uk/petitions/51746 as well and would like to make it clear that we also offer training about health and safety to business but these courses do not contain the suspected keywords.

Comment: I don't see how we can answer a geopolitical question here.  If there is a technical workaround, the government will find a way to defeat it.

Comment: Sounds like a load of bollocks to me...

Comment: BT said the only way they could think of, was to contact our local MP. Doesn't look hopeful :(

Comment: I was thinking some sort of text encoding to stop them picking up key words rather than just removing all relevant words?

Comment: @Ryan my question or the situation? :S

Comment: [*I was thinking some sort of text encoding*] ...which the Great Firewall Of Britain will either be aware of now, or will after it notices your site.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the longer we can keep it going the better, maybe they will rethink all of this after a while?

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I really don't understand what you are saying. Their systems use simple HTML crawlers looking for key words I assume.

Comment: maybe this question should be moved to Security SE?

Comment: @hozza, I don't know how the British system works, but content firewalls are often a good deal more sophisticated than that.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, perhaps you could provide some useful information then? or links/documentation? as I don't think talking about an unnamed system will alert the software to read/understand my post and then take action... This is not Skynet. Useful comments only please.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry you don't see my comments as useful. I apparently can't stop myself from leaving one more, thus: your Skynet comment is weird. I was talking about the ability of a firewall to detect trivial attempts to bypass it, like character substitutions or different character encodings. That's not AI - that's existed in similar systems for decades. In general, you're trying to use technical means to fix a regulatory problem. You may succeed for a little while, but not for long.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, as I have already said, any success/progress for any length of time would be wonderful. From my experience with content blocking systems, they work on content readable text and links to/from already blocked content on a rank system. Simple images or JavaScript encoding would circumvent this for significant length of time, until the system is updated to parse JS, unlikely. I'm asking about server side solutions. If you do not have any relevant information, I kindly ask you to stop commenting.

Comment: Would it help, if you made the content not indexable [prevent crawlers from access to certain content] and require the user to log in?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree ah, we kind of do this already with internal training content, but the external pages that advertise/explain the content need to be searchable :(

Comment: Host the content outside of the UK, and use `https`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch if only it were that simple, the blocks are being setup on the user ISP end, hosting the servers elsewhere (as we currently do, US) and https does not help :(

Answer (score 0):

What about "cheap" encryption? Of any sort, even ROT13 as this is not for secrecy purpose.
About the govt finding the workaround you're using, you could just increase the encryption strength to something more serious than ROT13. 
I don't think content firewalls will ever really attempt to crack any kind of encryption.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into this. Does anyone else have any related info? :)